# Is it allowed to pass NSManagedObject through performBlock of the same NSManagedContext?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data

Can I set the relationship between objects in DIFFERENT perform blocks of the SAME NSManagedContext?

I created a private context 
and used (just example):

```swift
let pContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
pContext.perform {
   let user = pContext.fetch(<fetch Request>).first
   pContext.performAndWait {
        let book = pContext.fetch(<another fetch request>).first
        book.name = "skjkjd"
        pContext.save()
        book.author = user
        pContext.save()
   }
}
```

May this code produce following error and in which cases?

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>       Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'author' between objects in different contexts

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken but the AppDelegate persistentContainer.viewContext is a singleton. You shouldn't pass the MOC across threads the way you are trying to do.

Take a look at the apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background

TRY (not tested):

```
    let pContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    pContext.perform {
        let user = pContext.fetch(<fetch Request>).first
        let userObjcID = user.objectID
            pContext.performAndWait {
                 let book = pContext.fetch(<another fetch request>).first
                 book.name = "skjkjd"
                 // pContext.save()
                 book.author = pContext.object(with: userObjcID)
        pContext.save()
   }
}
```

Comment: The private context is associated to serial queue so the documentation says that we mustn't pass objects between different queues(not threads). But I do it in the same private context.

I haven't found anything about different threads(only queues) in the documentation.

Maybe private context can use different queues for different performBlock? I haven't  found documentation about it.

Comment: Well if you are using the same context just different performBlocks, use the NSManagedObjectID, to get the reference of the managedObject from one block to the other

Comment: thank you, nice  to add a mark to the documentation to avoid such questions.